# How to fix 'TypeError: Menu2.button_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'button'' in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I wanted the button to print the message once it has been press it work for the first one but for the second I had TypeError: Menu2.button_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'button' what should I do about it
This is the code:

```
class Menu(View):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        super().__init__()
        self.ctx = ctx

    # Button for starting the quiz
    @discord.ui.button(label="Start Quiz", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
    async def button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        # Create and send the question embed
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.dark_gold(), description=Q1, title="Question 1")
        embed.set_author(name='Quiz: Which Kingdom of Xykolomania Fits You Best?')
        embed.set_footer(text="Please select an option:")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/350949422_1697426800701996_2053336980202314129_n.jpg?_nc_cat=108&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=Kn-DLyT1ndkAX8wHZQS&_nc_ht=scontent-yyz1-1.xx&oh=00_AfAutxrnArY02lXHabzGS2cFYKZrorpcU2FjBxOskk1ZSw&oe=647B8DCE')
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=Menu2(ctx=self.ctx))

class Menu2(View):
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        super().__init__()
        self.ctx = ctx
      
        options = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
        for option in options:
            # Create option buttons and assign the callback function
            button = discord.ui.Button(label=option, style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, emoji="")
            button.callback = self.button_callback
            self.add_item(button)
        
    # Check if the interaction is valid
    async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if interaction.user == self.ctx.author:
            return True
        await interaction.response.send_message("You can't interact with this menu.", ephemeral=True)
        return False

    # Callback function for the option buttons
    async def button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message('You Clicked it')
```

I wanted it to send a message 'You Clicked it'

Comment: Why do you use `@discord.ui.button` in one case and `button = discord.ui.Button(...)` in the other?

Answer (score 0):

The Button callback only gets the `interaction`.  It doesn't get the `button` as a parameter.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.Button.callback

Comment: Thank you sir it now make sense and I was able to make progress for my project